# Using an interface which extends a generic class

Tags: java, android, interface

I have a few variations of an ImageView.

All the variations need to implement the following interface:

```
public interface ResizableImageViewInterface {
    boolean resizeImageToView();
}
```

However, e.g. one class extends directly the ImageView class, another implements ImageViewTouch, which itself implements ImageView.

My problem is I need to call on the ImageView methods, and the method in the interface. E.g. in my cache loader:

```
public ImageLoader(String imageUrl, ResizableImageViewInterface view) {
    viewReference = new WeakReference<>(view);
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;

    view.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading);
}
```

This does not work, as a ResizableImageViewInterface does not have the setImageResource method. I thought I could do this the following which would indicate the inheritance:

```
public interface ResizableImageViewInterface extends ImageView
```

but as that is not possible. How can I create this relationship, in order that I have both these classes implements the interface as well have all the ImageView methods available. I could copy and declare the required methods in the interface, but that doesn't seem the right way to do it.

Comment: add the `setImageResource` method in interface `ResizableImageViewInterface`.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: exactly, what is your goal?

Comment: @sajan-chandran that is what I have done, but it doesn't sound like the proper way. I am trying to have a common interface, which extends ImageView but has an extra method for two classes which extend ImageView but not directly (with different sub classes).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up, as suggested, just to add the required methods to the interface.